# json, ASP.NET MVC, Create cascading drop down list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create cascading drop down box,
The first drop down box should be populated with movie titles
The second drop down box should be populated with dates associated with the movie titles.
I created a one to many relationship.

Here is my model generated using database first approach:

```
public partial class MovieDetail
{     
    public MovieDetail()
    {
        this.MovieDates = new HashSet<MovieDate>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
}

public partial class MovieDate
{
    public MovieDate()
    {
        this.Times = new HashSet<Time>();
    }

    public int MovieDateId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int MovieDetailsId { get; set; }

    public virtual MovieDetail MovieDetail { get; set; }
}
```

In my Controller:

```
public class MovieWhatsOnController : Controller
{
    public MovieEntities1 db = new MovieEntities1();

    // GET: MovieWhatsOn
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult TitleList(int MovieDetailsId)
    {
        var title = from s in db.MovieDetails
                    where s.Id == MovieDetailsId
                    select s.Title;

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(db.MovieDetails, "Id", "Title"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(title);
        }

    }

    public ActionResult DateList(int moviedetailsid)
    {
        var date = from s in db.MovieDates
                   where s.MovieDateId == moviedetailsid
                   select s.Date;

        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new SelectList(db.MovieDates, "MovieDateId", "Date"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return View(date);
    }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
@model MovieApp.Models.MovieDetail
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
}

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () 
    {
        $.getJSON(" MovieWhatsOn/TitleList", function (data) {
            var items="<option>-----</option>";
            $.each(data,function(i,title){
                items+="<option value'" +title.Value +"'>" +title.text +"</option>";

            });

            $("#Titles").html(items);
        });

        $("Titles").change(function(){
            $.getJSON(" MovieWhatsOn/DateList" + $("#Titles > option:selected").attr("value"), function (data){
                var items="<option>-----</option>";
                $.each(data,function(i,date){
                    items+="<option value'" +date.Value +"'>" +date.text +"</option>";

                });

                $("#Dates").html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label for="Titles">Title</label>
    <select id="Titles" name="Titles"></select>
    <br /><br />
    <label for="Dates">Dates</label>
    <select id="Dates" name="Dates"></select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />

}
```

At the moment when the title and date are not populating the drop down lists.

I am really unsure were I am going wrong. I am new to JSON and MVC.

Really appreciate your time your efforts! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Browser side (via firebug etc): Is the ajaax firing? are you getting a return?

App side: results of stepping through?

Comment: have you debugged the app with breakpoints? Is anything returned to the browser?

Comment: @MadMyche I will have ago at doing that, thanks

Comment: @MadMyche so I realize that my ajax is not firing but I do not know why?